# DataFrame from series, with values of index as rows/columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After a `groupby` and a `count` on a DataFrame, I have a series like this:

```
gender_neutral_death            gender
ascended                        Fem       103
                                Mal        69
burned by a tower of flame      Fem         5
                                Mal         1
burned by molten lava           Fem         4
                                         ... 
went to heaven prematurely      Mal         1
zapped themselves with a spell  Fem        10
                                Mal         7
zapped themselves with a wand   Fem         8
                                Mal        10
```

Now I would like to use 'gender' to build two columns 'Mal' and 'Fem', this my case it'd become:

```
gender_neutral_death        Mal    Fem
ascended                     69    103
burned by a tower of flame    1      5
[...]
```

The `to_frame()` method gives me **almost what I want**:

[image]

And applying `unstack` brings me closer but not quite:

[image]

How would I achieve the result I gave in the example above?

Comment: Use `by_gender.unstack(level=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed the result of the groupby / count operation is a pandas Series.

The `unstack()` function accepts a level (1 or 'gender') in this case:

```
s.unstack(level='gender').fillna(0).astype(int)
```